# A line in Reflections on the Revolution in France

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Edmund Burke's Reflections on the Revolution in France he says:

> "I flatter myself that I love a manly, moral, regulated liberty as well as any gentleman of that society, be he who he will ; and perhaps I have given as good proofs of my attachment to that cause, in the whole course of my public conduct. **I think I envy liberty as little as they do, to any other nation.**

I'm not sure what Burke means by the line, "I think I envy liberty as little as they do, to any other nation."

Could someone help explain what exactly he means by this line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think he means that he likes to give liberty to other people or nations and envies little the act of doing so. But why he envies little is explained in the subsequent paragraphs of this letter.

> ... I should therefore suspend my congratulations on the new liberty of France, until I was informed how it had been combined with government; with public force; with the discipline and obedience of armies; with the collection of an effective and well-distributed revenue; with morality and religion; with the solidity of property; with peace and order; with civil and social manners. All these (in their way) are good things too; and, without them, liberty is not a benefit whilst it lasts, and is not likely to continue long. The effect of liberty to individuals is that they may do what they please: we ought to see what it will please them to do, before we risk congratulations, which may be soon turned into complaints. Prudence would dictate this in the case of separate, insulated, private men; but liberty, when men act in bodies, is power. Considerate people, before they declare themselves, will observe the use which is made of power; and particularly of so trying a thing as new power in new persons, of whose principles, tempers, and dispositions they have little or no experience, and in situations, where those who appear the most stirring in the scene may possibly not be the real movers.

Comment: This is my interpretation too. It's an archaic, awkwardly-phrased sentence, and could be a bit more intelligible if the structure was changed: "I think I envy liberty to any other nation [just] as little as they do." And "envy" in this usage being akin to "begrudge".

Comment: @568ml I think it is not merely "akin" but equivalent to *begrudge. See [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed03arch#page/n987/mode/2up_). s.v. **Envy** *v.*, sense **3.**; and note that there are two citations of this sense with *to*, both 18th century. (But I don't think it's awkwardly phrased!)

Comment: So it is! That's a great find — thank you for sharing it!

Comment: But I will never quite understand the mind of followers of Burke who claimed 'unalienable rights' (sic) for themselves whilst 'owning' thousands of slaves! My hero of the age is Thomas Payne!